# Right click on PrimeFaces tree node does not trigger select event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using a PrimeFaces 6.2 `p:tree` component with a context menu which differ for each node. When I click left and then right the menu is rendered properly, but when I click right directly the menu is not updated. Any ideas how to solve it?

I know that there are some posts about ajax after right click (event `contextMenu`), but it does not help, because the context menu disappears.

Sample `p:tree` can look like:

```
<p:tree id="docs" value="#{treeContextMenuView.root}" var="doc"
    selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{treeContextMenuView.selectedNode}" dynamic="true">
    <p:ajax event="select" update="form:contextMenu" />
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
        collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
        <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="document" icon="ui-icon-document">
        <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="picture" icon="ui-icon-image">
        <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="mp3" icon="ui-icon-video">
        <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

and sample `p:contextMenu` like:

```
<p:contextMenu for="docs" id="contextMenu">
    <p:menuitem value="View" update="messages"
        actionListener="#{treeContextMenuView.displaySelectedSingle}"
        icon="ui-icon-search" />
    <p:menuitem value="Item for Documents"
        rendered="#{treeContextMenuView.selectedNode.data.name eq 'Documents'}"
        icon="ui-icon-print" />
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="docs"
        actionListener="#{treeContextMenuView.deleteNode}"
        icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

Full reproducible MVCE: https://github.com/szydra/primefaces-test

edit: Recently, I have found the same issue reported for `p:dataTable`:
[issue on github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2604).

Comment: Please create an MVCE reproducing the problem using this sample project: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: @Melloware Please see my example on [github](https://github.com/szydra/primefaces-test). I have copied the PrimeFaces showcase example and add a special item for 'Documents'. The context menu is not rendered properly, when you use only right click.

Comment: Excellent work on a reproducible sample. I would create a GitHub issue and reference that DataTable Issue you found on GitHub.  It definitely seems like a similar issue with a similar potential fix.

Comment: Please everone, stackoverlow 'requires' [mcve] to be posted inline here. Not an mcve like the ones PrimeFaces 'requires'... external sites have no guarantee to stay online in the future. See [ask] Please improve the question here

Comment: @Kukeltje Updated.